# В редакторе Unity модели видны в собранном проекте модели не видны(build) . В чём может быть дело?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

В редакторе :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В build :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки самой 3D модели:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Resolution and Presentation:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы вообще уверены, что эти объекты существуют в билде? Пыль от гусениц - ребенок "танка" в плане иерархии объектов?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Если выводить ошибки то в этой сцене ошибка : Serialized file size of 8.88 GB (9540477456 bytes) exceeds maximum. File name: 'Temp/StagingArea/Data/resources.assets'. Serialized files over 4.00 GB (4294967295 bytes) cannot be loaded by the player. Some likely ways to reduce this are utilizing asset bundles, re-balancing asset locations, or limiting their serialized size e.g. limiting the max

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Объекты существуют в редакторе

Comment: @RiotBr3aker танк ребёнок пустышки "Vehicles" ....потом пустышка под названием танка, и его все модификации

Comment: Так в ошибке прямым текстом сказано, что невозможно загрузить определенные ресурсы. Вы пробовали разбивать эти ресурсы по разным сериализованным файлам?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker нет можно указать пожалуйста указать ссылку как это делать ..... у меня видимо большая папка ресурсов